# How to extract chemdraw OLE objects from Excel table using Python?

Tags: python, ole-object, schemdraw

In excel, ChemDraw structure is EMBED("ChemDraw.Document.6.0",").

I would like to use Python to extract Chemdraw OLE-objects from an Excel table into the new excel sheet.

I tired using answer to similar qeustions, but without success.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.